# xExtend Values not updating

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am following the same code from this [Gist](http://bl.ocks.org/mhsmith/5732011)

What I needed is to update this xExtent dynamic based on new data comes

```
function updateLmits(){
  zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
   .x(x)
   .xExtent([-1000,1000])
   .y(y)
   .yExtent([-100,100])
   .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])

   .on("zoom", zoomed);
    zoomed()
}
```

But somehow new zoom still showing old 
Should I need to rebind that zoom ? or unbind old one before set new ?
test [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I47Y6TM4NISi8xpkhx2b?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry It was silly mistake. the zoom object binded with svg was old after updating zoom with new values I have to rebind that to svg else it wll use old one..

```
function updateLmits(){
zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
 .x(x)
 .xExtent([-1000,1000])
 .y(y)
  .yExtent([-100,100])
  .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

   svg.call(zoom);//<====
}
```